# How can I change this code so it will only specifically set the zero flag for greater than FFFDh?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I am trying to attain the first value that is greater than -3,
However I am stuck with this line of code:

```
cmp WORD PTR [esi],FFFDh            ; test sign bit
pushfd                              ; push flags on stack
add  esi,TYPE array
popfd                               ; pop flags from stack
loopnz next                         ; continue loop
```

If I do the cmp operation, the zero flag will only be set if `WORD PTR [esi] = FFFDh`
This loop will only stop if WORD PTR [esi] is either greater than or less than FFFDh.
How can I change this code so it will only specifically set the zero flag for greater than FFFDh.

```
.data
array  SWORD  -3,-6,-1,-10,10,30,40,4
sentinel SWORD  0

.code
main PROC
    mov esi,OFFSET array
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF array

next:
    cmp WORD PTR [esi],FFFDh            ; test sign bit
    pushfd                              ; push flags on stack
    add  esi,TYPE array
    popfd                               ; pop flags from stack
    loopnz next                         ; continue loop

    jnz  quit                           ; none found
    sub  esi,TYPE array                 ; ESI points to value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to use the zero flag for this. You should use a conditional jump out of the loop. Incidentally, you can also get rid of the `pushfd`/`popfd` and the post-loop `esi` adjustment:

```
next:
    cmp WORD PTR [esi],FFFDh
    jg found
    add  esi,TYPE array
    loop next                         ; continue loop
    jmp quit
found:
    ; ESI points to value
```

PS: make sure `LENGTHOF` returns the array size in number of elements and not bytes because you use it as iteration count.